# TeXstudio freezes when opening a macro

Tags: macros, texstudio

Since several weeks all my TeXstudio installations show this irritating behaviour:

1. Write a macro like `\cite`, `\input`, `\SI`, `\gls`, `\label`, ...
2. Type the opening bracket `{`
3. As soon as typing the `{` the CPU load rises to 100 % and TeXstudio is unresponsive for several seconds. I can type anything and the letters appear one after another - each after some seconds. When I don't type, the CPU goes down again until I type another letter.
4. As soon as typing the closing bracket `}` everything is fine again.

It happens most of the time, but not always. The same happens with copy and pasting those macros.

It mainly seems to be related to linking/referencing/including macros. This does not happen with stuff like `\footnote`, `\emph` etc. On the other hand, `\dfrac` is also suffering from this.

I tried deactivating interactive checking of citations, references and syntax in the options editor tab. No change of this.

I run TeXstudio 2.10.8 in Manjaro Linux on three different machines.

Anyone the same issue or an idea?

Comment: I've had a similar thing in TeXstudio when altering the document class. I thought it was because I've got a very large file, so I'm not sure if our problems are symptoms of the same issue or not.

Comment: I don't use it, but this is something like a search for completions going awry, like trying to look into very big files or directories. Maybe you can `strace` it to see which files it opens and look if there something strange...

Comment: To see all the files a program opens, you can use `strace program 2>&1 | grep "open"` on Linux system. There will be a lot of system files and libraries at start, but after that if you reproduce the problem it *can* point you to the error.

Comment: Nice tool, didn't know `strace`. Unfortunately, it opens files all the time - when pointing somewhere etc. - but when TeXstudio freezes after typing a macro nothing is opened. Doesn't seem to be a problem with loading big files. Even though my bibliography is big indeed: it always was and e.g. the siunitx files have not changed neither.

Comment: In parallel I have filed a bug report... https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/1736/

Comment: I just recognized it also happens with e.g. `\label` and `\dfrac`. Especially the latter has nothing to do with the document size...

Comment: Could you check which process is using 100% CPU? If it's some process that's spawned by texstudio, that information could help. Also, omit the grep part of @Rmano's comment to see if maybe some other syscall gets used excessively while it hangs.

Comment: When I do this, `strace` outputs "polling for event" as fast as possible (all the time, no matter if TeXstudio freezes or not). And the cpu usage of java rises to 100% on all cores.

Comment: That's a weird output of `strace` that I haven't seen before ([neither has google](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=strace%20polling%20for%20event)). Are you sure that this line is even output by strace and not the program itself?

Comment: Sorry, that was not the exact command. Just my description... Exactly it says:
`poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}, {fd=11, events=POLLIN}, {fd=16, events=POLLIN}, {fd=17, events=POLLIN}, {fd=130, events=POLLIN}], 8, 215) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLIN}])
read(5, "\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16)         = 8
recvmsg(6, 0x7ffee410f640, 0)           = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)`
When I start TeXstudio without `strace` it just outputs some `level change` lines.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I found a temporary solution. By deactivating the option "load included files automatically" (just translated from German to English, no guarantee it's exactly named like this) in the editor's tab of TeXstudio's options the freezing behaviour is gone.

But of course I'll have to find all the references, citations etc. manually now. Not much better than using an ordinary text editor... So it's a way to work again, but not the way I like to have.

Comment: Did you find any better solution in the end?

Comment: Unfortunately not. However, not long after that time I have changed my job and had not much to do in TeX since then :( So I have stopped researching and also have no idea how newer versions behave. Sorry!

Comment: Well, thanks for the late reply nevertheless! :)